# How to use a variable to pass an object key into an Angular Directive?

Tags: angularjs, codemirror

I'm using the [Code Mirror](http://codemirror.net/) directive to format text areas as code.

**What is working:**

```
<textarea ui-codemirror type="textarea" ng-model="x"></textarea>
```

You can set the options up like so

```
<textarea ui-codemirror="editorOptions" type="textarea" ng-model="x"></textarea>
```

and in your Controller:

```
$scope.editorOptions = {
            name: 'javascript',
            json: true,
            smartIndent: false,
            tabSize: 2,
            lineWrapping : true,
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: 'javascript'
        }
```

**What's not working:**

I'm trying to dynamically change the editorOptions based on another part of the model (I'm supporting Javascript and Markdown).

So I'm trying this:

```
$scope.editorOptions = {
        json: {
            name: 'javascript',
            json: true,
            smartIndent: false,
            tabSize: 2,
            lineWrapping : true,
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: 'javascript'
        },
        markdown: {
            name: 'markdown',
            json: false,
            smartIndent: false,
            tabSize: 2,
            lineWrapping : true,
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: 'markdown'
        }
    };
```

and then this in the HTML:

```
<select ng-model='editorType' required ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in editorTypes'></select>
<textarea ui-codemirror="editorOptions[editorType]" type="textarea" ng-model="x"></textarea>
```

My question is- How can I use the value of the select model (editorType) to specify which options object is being used in the code mirror directive?

I've tried

```
<textarea ui-codemirror="editorOptions.[editorType]" type="textarea" ng-model="x"></textarea>
<textarea ui-codemirror="editorOptions[$scope.editorType]" type="textarea" ng-model="x"></textarea>
```

all to no avail.

Anyone know what the proper way to do this is?

Many, many thanks!

**Update**
I believe this is the correct syntax:

```
ui-codemirror="editorOptions[editorType]".
```

I think there is a problem with the directive not realizing the variable has changed.

Comment: could u share your fiddle or plunker demo

Comment: I believe the problem may be the directive isn't aware that the $scope.editorType variable has changed.

Comment: @Hairgami_Master I think you're very likely barking up the right try best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this will work for you without forking ui-codemirror. The code within UI-codemirror does `opts = angular.extend({}, options, scope.$eval(attrs.uiCodemirror));` at the beginning, but it does not watch for updates.

If you forked ui-codemirror from: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror/blob/master/ui-codemirror.js and then added something like

```
attrs.$observe('uiCodemirror', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal) {
    opts = angular.extend({}, options, scope.$eval(attrs.uiCodemirror));
    codeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(elm[0], opts); //or maybe $timeout(deferredCodemirror) ??
  }
});
```

Then it might work, but I haven't tested that so I have no idea if it really would work. Maybe this will give you an idea of how to create the directive you need.

Another alternative, which would be considerably heavier, would be to instantiate two codemirrors and switch between the two... but I really don't like that option too much.

Comment: Thanks man- I looked through the code and was trying to understand how it worked. I don't know enough about to directives to change that line you mentioned to two-way binding or something instead of the init style value it does now. I've coded around it for now, but would prefer a more elegant approach. Cheers!

Comment: You wouldn't "change" that line, you'd just add a watch later that re-initializes CodeMirror. That tidbit I posted will check to see if ui-codemirror attribute changes, and then re-run the CodeMirror constructor.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan- I my hackaround was exactly what you thought- two code mirrors. I'm going to try your technique when I have a minute to breathe. Thank you so much. Leaving it unanswered for now in case someone from CodeMirror happens by.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Jonathan's reply:

```js
attrs.$observe('uiCodemirror', function (newVal, oldVal) 
{
  if(newVal !== oldVal) 
  {
    opts = angular.extend({}, options, scope.$eval(attrs.uiCodemirror));
    var keys = Object.keys(opts)
    if(keys.length != 0)
    {
      keys.forEach(function(i)
      {
        var v = opts[i];
        codeMirror.setOption(i, v);
      });

      $timeout(function() { codeMirror.refresh()} );
    }
  }
});
```